# Travelling to Russia with two passports

Tags: passports, dual-nationality, hong-kong

I'm a Hong Kong citizen who is holding both the Hong Kong Passport and the British Nation (Oversea) Passport.With the HK passport, I can stay in Russia for 14 days without visa.

I'm now staying in France with the working holiday visa which is on my British passport. But the problem is that I wanna have a short trip to Russia now. There're two plans:

Plan A:

1. Leaving France with the British passport
2. Entering and Leaving Russia with the Hong Kong passport
3. Going back to France with the British passport

But which passport should I use for booking the ticket? And will I get into any trouble while passing the border control?

Plan B:

1. Forget about the British passport. Just using the Hong Kong passport at all.

But I wonder whether I would get into any trouble at the French border control because my Hong Kong passport has no entry stamp of EU and then I use it to leave and come back France .

Which plans should I go for? or another other options?

Comment: Why do you think that your current staying in France is a problem?

Comment: Just posted my Plan A & B